# Move constructor

Tags: c++

Estaba revisando este código y me encontré con algunas lineas que no entiendo , es sobre constructores de movimiento, las dejo marcadas:
¿¿Que quiere decir toda esta linea??

```
MemoryBlock& operator=(const MemoryBlock& other) //¿¿Que quiere decir toda esta linea??
   {
      std::cout << "In operator=(const MemoryBlock&). length = "
                << other._length << ". Copying resource." << std::endl;

      if (this != &other)//¿¿¿que hace esta linea???
      {
         // Free the existing resource.
         delete[] _data;

         _length = other._length;
         _data = new int[_length];
         std::copy(other._data, other._data + _length, _data);
      }
      return *this;
   }

   // Retrieves the length of the data resource.
   size_t Length() const
   {
      return _length;
   }

private:
   size_t _length; // The length of the resource.
   int* _data; // The resource.
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
MemoryBlock& operator=(const MemoryBlock& other) //¿¿Que quiere decir toda esta linea??
```

Aqui estas sobreescribiendo el operador de asignacion `=`. Este es el que dicta como se va a copiar el objeto cuando hagas algo como `A = B`.

```cpp
if (this != &other)//¿¿¿que hace esta linea???
```

Estas revisando que no asignes el objeto a si mismo. `this` es el puntero de tu objeto. Y `&other` es el puntero a el otro. Si ambos son iguales entoces estas haciendo algo como `A = A`. Si no pones ese checkeo de seguridad cuando corra la copia vas a borrar el objeto y crear uno nuevo.

```cpp
 delete[] _data; // Borras los datos que tenias

 _length = other._length; 
 _data = new int[_length]; // Reasignas el objeto
 std::copy(other._data, other._data + _length, _data); // Y le asignas datos inexistentes al objeto.
```

Answer (score 0):

En C++, todas las funciones se ajustan a este *protocolo*:

```
TipoDevuelto nombre( Argumentos ... )
```

Por lo tanto

```
MemoryBlock& operator=(const MemoryBlock& other)
```

es la definición de una funcióm-biembro que devuelve una referencia a una instancia del tipo `MemoryBlock`, cuyo nombre es [`operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment), y requiere como argumento una referencia constante a una instancia del tipo `MemoryBlock`.

Mientras que esta otra línea

```
this != &other
```

es una simple comparación, en donde se comprueba que el valor de `this` [sea distinto](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) a la dirección de memoria en la que existe el argumento `other`. Vamos, viene a comprobar que no estas llamando a la función usando la misma instancia como argumento.

Así que, como verás, de `move constructor` nada de nada :-)

Comment: `if (this != &other)` está comparando punteros, no referencias a objetos, el operador `!=` del objeto no sería llamado, sería `bool operator!=(P, P);`.

Comment: @Manuel ¡ Huy ! Tienes razón, me he *columpiado* aquí. Edito y elimino eso. Gracias por el aviso :-)